# Updating array in mongodb in safe mode

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'd like to update an array element in mongodb. In the mongodb shell this works:

```
db.ipolls.update({_id:"5Qu9fXG84tNSZo7sv","players.label":"R1"},{$inc:{"players.$.score":1}});
```

But when I run this in meteor:

```
Ipolls.update( {_id:pollster,"players.label":notChosen.label},{$inc:{"players.$.comparisons":1}});
```

I get the error: Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]

Is it possible to run this query on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

On the client you can only use the `_id` field as a selector. You've used `{_id:pollster,"players.label":notChosen.label}`

This is a meteor thing, its just to make it a bit safer. You could theoretically create a weird selector and get information out of the `.allow` rule checks were this not the case.

Query for the document first, then use that to update it:

```
var doc_to_update = Ipolls.findOne({_id:pollster,"players.label":notChosen.label});
Ipolls.update( {_id: doc_to_update._id},{$inc:{"players.$.comparisons":1}});
```

Comment: I was including the second half of the selector so that I would update the correct element of the array. How do I select the correct element if that is not in the selector? If I try your suggestion I get: Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.

Comment: I didn't see that you were using the `$` operator. The `$` operator isn't yet supported by meteor on the client side. There is an outstanding issue on github about this : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/153

Comment: It is supported on the server side so you could use a method/call to interface the command up to the server